# Finding the formula for the number of half-lives of a substance, given the formula for its decay $Q(t) = Q_0e^{-ln(\sqrt[25]{2})t}$

Tags: calculus

> The disintegration of a radioactive substance is well modeled by a law
> of the type:
>
> $$Q(t) = Q_0\cdot e^{-kt}$$
>
> being $Q(t)$ the remaining mass, at instant $t$, of an initial
> quantity $Q_0$, that corresponds to the instant $t=0$.
>
> Substance A has
> an half-life time of 25 years.
>
> Write the law for the disintegration of substance A, in function of $Q_0$, for the number $n$ of half-lives

Earlier I found that for substance A, $k = \frac{-\ln(0.5)}{25}$ (my book says this is correct)

My book says the solution is:
$$Q(n) = Q_0e^{ln(0.5n)}$$

I don't understand this problem. Shouldn't a substance have only one half-life? Otherwise it wouldn't be half, would it? Can someone explain this problem and my books solution?

Comment: Are you sure about $k$? $k=-\frac{\ln(\frac{1}{2})}{25}=\frac{\ln(2)}{25}$

Comment: @MattG88 My mistake, I'll edit it

Comment: @AliceIsDead The solution must be $Q(n)=Q_0e^{ln(0.5)\cdot n}$.$ n$ is outside of the ln-function.

Comment: @AliceIsDead Did you get my comment ?

Comment: @callculus  yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that

\begin{equation}
Q(t)=Q_0 e^{-\frac{\ln2}{25}t}
\end{equation}

If $t=25n$:

\begin{equation}
Q(25n)=Q_0 e^{-\frac{\ln2}{25}25n}=Q_0 e^{-n\ln2}
\end{equation}

25 is the half-live time i.d. the time we need to have half of a substance, so if we have 100 atoms, after 25 years we'll have 50 atoms, after others 25 years we'll have 25 atoms and so on...

Answer (score 1):

> Write the law for the disintegration of substance $A$, in function of
>   $Q_0$, for the number $n$ of half-lives.

$n$ is the number of half lives. If $n=1$ then 25 years have passed. Thus

$Q(n)=Q_0\cdot e^{ln(0.5)\cdot n}=Q_0\cdot 0.5^n$

After $100$ years it exists $Q(4)=0.5^4 Q_0 =\frac{1}{16}Q_0$

**Remark**

$Q(n)$ is only equal to $Q(t)$ if $25n=t$ and $n \in \mathbb N_0$